# SVN post-commit works only manually

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, post-commit

HI,

I've created a batch file called post-commit.bat and placed it under the /hooks directory.

The content of the file is:

```
TestCS.exe
```

The content of the exe file is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            // create a writer and open the file
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("date.txt");

            // write a line of text to the file
            tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

            // close the stream
            tw.Close();
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

When I double-click on post-commit.bat, it creates the date.txt file.

When I commit in SVN, it takes time, and eventually gives me the following message:
[alt text http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/3894/exception.jpg](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/3894/exception.jpg)

What can be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing to do would be to launch the debugger and get a better idea of where the problem is occurring.

I *would* suggest that you should use a `using` statement for your `TextWriter`, and avoid catching and swallowing all exceptions without any attempt to even log the error.

Is that *really* your whole code? You're not using `args` at all? It's hard to see how that code would lead to an `IndexOutOfRangeException`...

Comment: I've tried the using statement, still the same. Even deleted the string args[]. Still the same.

Comment: I figured it out.
When running the testCS.exe, it apparently looked for the file in /SVNServer/bin and not in the hooks folder. In the bin folder I had a testCS.exe file with IndexOutOfRangeException.

Thanks.

Comment: I nearly mentioned "are you sure you're running the binary you think you're running" but didn't bother in the end. Oops.